# RemoveMarkerMixin in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I'm trying to write a mixin model in Django:

```
class RemoveMarkerMixin(db.models.Model):
    marker = db.models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

and use it like this:

```
class Measure(utils.RemoveMarkerMixin, db.models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        app_label = "core"

class MeasureUnit(utils.RemoveMarkerMixin, db.models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    measure = models.ForeignKey('core.Measure', related_name='units')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        app_label = "core"
```

Now I want to remove all the models with some marker like this:

```
RemoveMarkerMixin.objects.filter(marker='upload_wave1').delete()
```

But actually I can't do this(it's by design). Is there any way to achieve similar behavior?

Comment: I think, you will need do it directly, like : MeasureUnit.objects.filter(marker='upload_wave1').delete() and Measure.objects.filter(marker='upload_wave1').delete()

Comment: it works. But it's error prone in case when there is more then 2 models. And if want to inherit one more model from such mixin I need to find all the places and add a new line `NewModel.objects....`

Comment: i updated my answer, use __subclasses__() :P

Comment: the problem is solved?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this:

```
for model in RemoveMarkerMixin.__subclasses__():
    for model.objects.filter(marker='upload_wave1').delete()
```

I think it is the best approach in your case.

Comment: Yep, I'm looking for something like this. I will try and return to you.

Comment: Another point, you doesn't need, inherit the  db.models.Model on Measure and MeasureUnit, because the RemoveMarkerMixin, already inherits.

Answer (score 1):

No, i don't think its possible to query based on `RemoveMarkerMixin` model as its an abstract Model and no tables are created for it.

From the docs on [Abstract base classes:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)

> Abstract base classes are useful when you want to put some common
>   information into a number of other models. You write your base class
>   and put `abstract=True` in the `Meta` class. **This model will then
>   not be used to create any database table.** Instead, when it is used
>   as a base class for other models, its fields will be added to those of
>   the child class.

If you need to query either you have to **do the filtering separately** on `Measure` and `MeasureUnit` model **or use [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) instead.**